# What does みても mean here? Problem from workbook

Tags: conjugations

From "Japanese for Busy People Level II" p 46, there is the following question:

Fill in the blank with the appropriate particle:

この　くつを　（　　　）みても　いいですか。（はきます）

In other words, modify はきます so that the sentence makes sense when the modified word fills the blank.

This book is slowly introducing kanji, so you can see there are none here.

I know:
このくつ　mean these shoes.
はきます mean to put on.
いいですか。 is asking permission whether it is okay.

If the みても were not there, I think the sentence would make sense if te-form (はいて) filled the blank. But the みても is really confusing me. I really don't know what it means! I suppose it's just te-form みます (to look). But, I have no idea what it's doing in this sentence. Also, the particle も doesn't make sense to me.

I did learn something recently, which may or may not be related, even though it's not exactly helping me here... That is, using a te-form verb followed by みます, means "to try to do that verb." But in this sentence, it seems opposite. In other words, if I'm not mistaken, one could say, "～をはいてみますいいですか。" Which would mean, "is it okay if I try to put these on?" I could easily be mistaken, especially with particles.

Sorry to ramble, but I'm just trying to explain my current level of understanding.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: "～をはいてみますいいですか。" doesn't work, but "～をはいてみます、いいですか。" and "～をはいてみます。いいですか。" are OK. You might have heard one of the last two in conversation, which is why you think the first one is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence wants to be translated as

> Would it be possible if I try on these shoes? *or more literally*
>   Would it be alright if I try to put on these shoes?

Now do backwards substitution, using the "try to [verb]" construction you learned.

Also ～をはいてみますいいですか is ungrammatical.

Comment: Hint: みて is the te-form of みます.

Comment: So, "はいてみます" is not "try to put on"?

Comment: It is, but you can't append いいですか. You should make はいてみます compatible with the construction ～てもいいですか. And for that you may use the hint above.

Comment: Am I being too pedagogical?

Comment: No, you're not being too pedagogical. Actually I prefer that, but at my current level, it may require a lot of back-and-forth. So, let me see if I understand correctly. If the sentence ends with the verb, then みます is appropriate. If we are appending いいですか to a verb, then it requires a も particle preceding it, and the verb must be in て form? Then, 「～をはいてみてもいいですか」. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is correct. There may be other ways of ending a sentence with いいですか (just not ~ますいいですか), but that is not important. The point is that the example sentence gave you the construction ~てもいいですか, which you were to combine with ～てみる to give ～てみてもいいですか, as you understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The みる in the てみる construction changes just as any other 'ru' verb. The textbook is throwing a slight curveball by making you recognize two different patterns and slot it in appropriately.

The first, as you recognized, is the てみる pattern, which means to try. So you are right that it should by はいてみます. However it is not as simple as just changing it to はいてみます and being done with it, since you are also asking for *permission*, which as you know is accomplished by ～て（も）いいですか. So you need to combine these two ideas: take はいてみます and add てもいいですか. You do this by taking はいてみます and putting it into its own て form, which then connects into てもいいですか with no problem. So your final sentence should look like

> このくつをはいてみてもいいですか

Just remember that the みる in てみる needs to be conjugated like any other verb.